# In Java, SecurityException is thrown by JVM or the application?

Tags: java, runtimeexception

I'm studying for the OCA exam, and I couldn't find anything about SecurityException in the OCA book. When i looked up on the internet, i didn't discover if this exception is thrown by the JVM or/and by the application. Can someone please, tell me?

Comment: See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityException.html

Comment: The source code is the ultimate truth: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/file/06222165c35f/src/hotspot/share/oops/instanceKlass.cpp#l2771

Answer (score 0):

it is thrown by JVM

"The SecurityException class extends the RuntimeException class and thus, belongs to those exceptions that can be thrown during the operation of the Java Virtual Machine (JVM). It is an unchecked exception and thus, it does not need to be declared in a method's or a constructor's throws clause"  from 
https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-securityexception-how-to-solve-securityexception/

Answer (score 0):

A [Security Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/security.html) in the JVM would be expected to be the primary use case for a [SecurityException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityException.html), however there's nothing to prevent applications choosing to throw this exception should they feel it suits their need.